# How do I solve this mega hairy ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently stuck on finding a solution for the following ODE:

$$ xy' -y = \frac{x^{2}} {\tan(x)\cos^2(x)}$$

I have really no clue where to begin solving either the homogeneous or particular part. Can anyone share his/her wisdom?

Answer (score 2):

Use $$\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)'=\frac{xy'-y}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Suppose you do not happen to guess this.  Then what?  Does your textbook have something about "integrating factors"?  Here, it turns out that the integrating factor is $1/x^2$.  If an integrating factor depends only on $x$ (or only on $y$), then there are calculaitons that let you find it.

Comment: @GEdgar I need to read about this thing. It's interesting, that you say.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you guessed this. I did got: $Y_h = C_1x$, and for rewriting the right part: $ \frac{x^{2}} {\sin(x)\cos(x)}$. But $ \frac{y'} {x}$? That's some kind of wizardy.

Comment: @d saline It's not wizardy. It's just  $\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the existing answer, $$\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^\prime=\frac{\sec^2 x}{\tan x}\implies \frac{y}{x}=\ln|\tan x|+C\implies y=x\ln|\tan x|+Cx.$$